# Max and min value of array (C pointer)

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void find(int a[], int n, int *min, int *max){
    int tmp, i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i] < a[j]){
                tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    *max = *a;
    *min = *(a + n);
    
}

int main(){
    int a[100];
    int n, *min, *max;
    printf("husnegtiinn elementiin toog oruul: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    find(a, n, min, max);
    printf("ih ni : %d \nbaga ni : %d", *max, *min);
    
}
```

I am trying to sort the array from user and get the min and max values in those pointers. I am having hard time figuring out how to pass pointers through functions. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `*(a + n);` is outside of the initialized elements in the array. `*(a + n - 1)` (or simpler `a[n-1]`) is the last element to which you assigned values.

Comment: The pointers `min` and `max` are not initialized, so it's illegal to dereference and assign values like `*max = *a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `*(a + n)` is outside of the initialized elements in the array. `*(a + n - 1)` (or simpler `a[n-1])` is the last element to which you assigned values.
- `min` and `max` should not be `int*`s but `int`s.

Example:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void find(int a[], int n, int *min, int *max){
    if(n < 1) return;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i] < a[j]){
                int tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    *max = a[0];
    *min = a[n - 1]; // the last element
    
}

int main(){
    int a[100];
    int n, min, max; // corrected types
    printf("husnegtiinn elementiin toog oruul: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1 || n > 100) return 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    find(a, n, &min, &max); // take the addresses of `min` and `max`
    printf("ih ni : %d \nbaga ni : %d", max, min);
}
```